# Diferente layout na última linha do datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Tenho um `datagrid` onde mostro valores referente ao começo e ao fim de um período. Para isso, eu criei a `columntemplate` abaixo com 2 `textblocks`, mas na última linha, eu mostro um valor que é a diferença entre esses 2 primeiros valores. Eu gostaria de centralizar o primeiro textblock na última linha visto que somente ele é populado nesse caso.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Officer11Nome}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                       />
            <TextBlock Text="Abertura" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       />

            <TextBlock Text="Fechamento" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       />
        </Grid>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Officer1Abertura}" Margin="2,0,2,0" TextAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Officer1Fechamento}" Margin="2,0,2,0" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei uma outra propriedade com as configurações que eu precisava, assim, como as demais não são populadas nesse caso, o valor se ajustou bem.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Officer1Percentagem}" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Officer1Abertura}" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Officer1Fechamento}" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2"/>
```